# Bookmarklet not appending in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, bookmarklet

I have written a bookmarklet that functions just fine in Chrome and Firefox but it IE 10 it fails to append to the document. I believe it has something to do with it being listed as "unrated" in the IE favorites bar, but I am not sure what part of the code is triggering that:

```
<a href="javascript:(function() {
    var elem=document.createElement('script');
    elem.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    elem.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.joshdforbes.com/web2mobile/
      web2mobile.js?t='+(new Date().getTime()));
    document.body.appendChild(elem); 
})()">Web2Mobile</a>
```

Having a hard time finding any information on the internet about what the differences are in IE10 that would be causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me but I'm on IE8. Did you compress it first?

```
javascript:(function(){var elem=document.createElement('script');elem.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');elem.setAttribute('src','http://www.joshdforbes.com/web2mobile/web2mobile.js?t='+(new Date().getTime()));document.body.appendChild(elem);})()
```

I did get the warning message initially, but I ignored it and it worked.

Comment: yeah, sorry I just spaced it out for some readability on here. It works for me in IE8 and IE9, but for some reason not in IE10.

Comment: nope I was wrong: I guess I didn't have it compressed. The code you pasted worked. Many Thanks

Comment: I use this page http://subsimple.com/bookmarklets/jsbuilder.htm to test and compress bookmarklets, but there are others around. Andy.